# Automating backup of Amazon S3 data - Alternatives to Bucket Commander?

Tags: backup, amazon-s3

I need to back up an entire Amazon S3 110 GB bucket on an automatic basis, to a location only accessible to me. We do not store data physically, all our data is in the cloud, so what I am looking for is automated cloud-to-cloud backup. Probably I would create another Amazon S3 bucket in another zone to host the backup.

Changes to the data in the bucket tend, on an ongoing basis, to be proportionately minor.

Most Amazon S3 File Manager Utilities are not oriented to scheduling backups of S3 data. Bucket Commander does not presently support copying between two buckets that are in two different AWS accounts.  Cloudberry's Cloud Migrator is in beta, and at the moment only handles small transfers.

So it seems no backup software now available does the job.

Comment: I don't know if this might be of assistance: http://serverfault.com/questions/9171/aws-s3-bucket-backups

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule automatic backups to [Glacier](https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/) by [enabling versioning](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/enable-bucket-versioning.html) for your bucket and setting a [lifecycle rule](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/lifecycle-configuration-bucket-with-versioning.html)

I'm not sure if you can set this to another zone though if you are doing this as an extra degree of safety it [wouldn't be necessary](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#data-protection_anchor).